# Change font and size of strbody element which is referencing an excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I know my code is very clumsy, I am trying my best to make something out of it.

The idea behind is to have an excel sheet with all the relevant details and based on this sheet, emails with the respective relevant content shall be sent.

The emails starts with strbody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _

Here cell.row A is the greeting (either Dear Sir or Dear Madam) and cell.row B is the name of the person.

If I run the code, everything works fine but the font of this code line is messed up. It shows in times new roman but I wish to have it in arial size: 10pt. I tried everything but always getting errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test1()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim strbody As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error GoTo cleanup



For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "ENG" Then
        On Error Resume Next

       With OutMail
        .display

    strbody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
    & "<p style= font-family:arial;font-size:10pt> Welcome </p>" _
    & IIf(Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "incomplete", "<p style= font-family:arial;font-size:10pt>Please do not forget to complete your registration:<p/> " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value, "<p> <p/>") _
    & "<h3  style= font-family:arial;font-size:11pt><font color=#5b9bd5><u>Check-in & Check-out</u></font></h3>" _
    & "<p style= font-family:arial;font-size:10pt>Check-In: <b>ab 15:00 Uhr</b> & Check-out: <b>bis 10:00 Uhr</b> Other hours on request </p>" _
    & "<p style= font-family:arial;font-size:10pt>Thanks</b></p>" _

            .Attachments.Add ("G:\E-Mail Vorlagen\Anhang\Anreise Infos\Nützliche Informationen.pdf")


            .To = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
            .Subject = "Your arrival" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value
            .htmlbody = strbody & .htmlbody
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML


        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell


cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you change the font in the cells instead of using HTML tags?

Comment: Thats what I tried to do (in Excel and in Outlook) but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes (i.e. *ticks* ) to isolate your style commands.

```
...
& "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:10pt;'> Welcome </p>"
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but unfortunately the quotations marks at the beginning and at the end of <p> are causing problems with the quotation marks of the cell reference. See here: 

strbody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:10pt;'> Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value </p>" _

I also tried double quotation marks "" "" at the beginning and the end, but still no luck..